# Use Cases with single dependency in Clean Architecture

Tags: java, clean-architecture

Is it worth to create a Use Case class when it has only one single dependency and its execution just call a method of that dependency?

```
public class GetOrdersUseCase {
    private OrdersManager ordersManager;

    public GetOrderUseCase(OrdersManager ordersManager) {
        this.ordersManager = ordersManager;
    }

    public List<Order> execute() {
        ordersManager.getOrders();
    } 
}
```

Comment: Is it worth it? Absolutely. I wish every use-case solution could be like that. Maintainable, easily read, responsible, and independent. If you consumed that use-case elsewhere you would be violating SRP somewhere else, or creating a dependency elsewhere effecting your maintainability.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, in order to simplify future maintenance, since one of the main concepts behind the Clean architecture is that there should be a one-to-one mapping between your use case classes and the use cases in the documentation. It makes easier to discover which classes implement what.